# Pack Javascript code without ending semicolon?

Tags: javascript, packer

So I read this [guide](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/) a while ago and I stopped using semicolons after every line statement in Javascript.

I want to show my SaaS application to a company hoping for some contract work. Most of the work is done in Javascript and I don't want the company to simply copy my JS code (and figure out the rest). So I wanted to [pack it](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) (with Base62 encode).

Here is a sample of my code:

```
    var options = {
        averageCenter  : true,
        gridSize       : 40,
        maxZoom        : 16,
        imagePath      : 'common/images/m',
        imageExtension : 'png'
    }

    var marker_cluster = new MarkerClusterer( MAP, MARKERS, options )

    marker_cluster.setCalculator
    (
        function( markers, numStyles ) {
            var index = 0
            var count = markers.length.toString()

            if     ( count < 5  ) index = 1
            else if( count < 20 ) index = 2
            else if( count < 40 ) index = 3
            else if( count < 80 ) index = 4
            else                  index = 5

            return {
                text  : count,
                index : index
            }
        }
    )
```

But Dean Edwards' Packer requires you to end every statement with a semicolon. Do I need to manually go back to insert a semicolon or is there another packer that doesn't require a semicolon, *then* pack it with Dean Edward's Packer?

Comment: I hope you have your asbestos suit on.

Comment: Why in the heck would you write all javascript code without line-ending semi-colons?

Comment: You'll save more bandwidth in minifying your code with semi-colons than you will with refusing to add them. JavaScript is not Python, although much of it works similarly.

Comment: The solution most likely involves a JS parser; one which could read the semicolon-less code and emit code with semicolons.

Comment: I got used to writing in Python lol. You should see how often I forget to add a semicolon in PHP.

Comment: Skimmed and scanned that "guide", ran across this little gem, *"My advice on JSLint: don’t use it. Why would you use it? If you believed that it helps you have less bugs in your code, here’s a newsflash; only people can detect and solve software bugs, not tools. So instead of tools, get more people to look at your code."* It is obvious to me that Mislav has completely missed the point of JSLint. JSLint doesn't catch bugs, it's simply a tool to help make them visible. You don't catch ants with a flashlight, but you wont know you have an ant problem in the dark corner of your basement without it

Comment: I think the last example of that guide (d + e).print() it's **enough** a good reason to put semicolons on each line... You'll never find that error otherwise. So my suggestion is to put semicolons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) doesn't seem to have any issue.  However, I would note that neither this nor the Packer are obfuscators.  Packer actually has decode functionality [built-in](http://yaisb.blogspot.com/2006/10/defeating-dean-edwards-javascript.html), though you need a simple trick to use it.

Even dedicated obfuscation tools are mostly a waste of time.  Your code can still be recovered with enough effort.

Finally, I recommend you do use semi-colons.  Even that article admits that it caused him a problem *several* times.  I also think the semi-colons do make the return statement problem much more obvious; further, in other languages I do sometimes put a line break there for long returns.